# SQL Server 2017 Remote access

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2017

I have tried every conceivable permutation for hours to try to connect to a remote `SQL Server 2017` using `SSMS`. I keep getting:

```
Logging failed for user xxx. (Microsoft SQL Server Error 18456)
```

- I know SQL Server is running on the remote machines since I can log
  in locally there using SSMS.
- SQL Browser is running.
- TCP/IP is enabled. There are no dynamic
  ports in IP All.
- I know the `firewall` is not a problem since I can
  telnet to port 1433 from the remote machine, and I added the rule to allow access.
- I have "Enable Remote Access" turned on in SQL Server.
- I have both Windows and SQL Server Authentication enabled.
- I have user mappings for the given databases.
- I can connect locally using SSMS with the Sql Server Auth user/passwd that I am trying to use remotely.

When logging in from the remote client in `SSMS`:

- I use an IP address for the server (although I can also browse to the server as I have UDP 1434 open).
- I use SQL Server Authentication.

I looked at `Event Viewer` on the SQL Server machinee to see if it gives me more clues as to why the log in is failing, but it is worthless.

I saw [this](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/troubleshooting-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-login-failed-user/), but it is of no help.

**What on earth could be left that is the problem?**

Comment: "I use SQL Server Authentication." <-- Well, you seemed to have covered all the transport layer issues. Did you ensure the credentials you are using are valid and have appropriate authorization?

Comment: I can connect locally using SSMS with the Sql Server Auth user/passwd, but can't on the remote machine using SSMS and using the same user/passw. This is maddening.

Comment: Try the MS [connectivity problem solver](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4009936/solving-connectivity-errors-to-sql-server).

Comment: Try the sql server error log instead of the event viewer. Also, see if this helps --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Ok, that helps, the logs say, "Login is disabled, and the password is incorrect." State 7. But that is nonsense. I can log in locally with that user, and the same password!

Comment: Make sure you are not using windows authentication when you log in locally.

Comment: Right, I made sure I log in locally with SQL Server Authentication. See last bullet point in OP. No progress.

Comment: I am beginning to believe that maybe using the IP adress instead of a FQ server name is not cool? Problem is, when I browse to the server, and I use the name in SSMS, that doesn't work at all.

Comment: I finally got it to work. I don't really understand why it started working. The only thing I did differently is I used the View->Register Server method, browsing to the server, not using an IP, tried the SQL Server Auth method with user/pwd, and it works.